# Removing date from Google SERP

Tags: seo, google, search-results

We are going through our site analysing the SEO.  I find that sometimes on a google results page, some results show a date, others don't.  Example (from same query):

[image]

I prefer the result not to have the date in it, as 20 Oct 2009 probably has an adverse effect on the clickability of the result.

Is this Google putting it in?  Or the page itself?  Or a combination of both (IE, if over a certain age, it includes date).

The two URLs are:

http://www.scirra.com/forum/perlin-noise-plugin_topic38498.html

http://www.scirra.com/forum/dungeon-maze-generator_topic40611.html

Any way to remove the dates?  I'm thinking, if the age of the thread is > 4 months don't display the date on the page, then Google might not find a date reference for it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately there is not a way to tell Google not to do that as of right now.

But [this web page](http://www.dollarshower.com/how-to-remove-date-stamp-from-google-serp-description/) had a couple of suggestions worth mentioning:

> 1. Use image based dates instead of the usual theme (PHP) generated server
>      side time stamp. In this case, you
>      have to convert the date string to
>      images and hence it may not be very
>      easy to create the image styles that
>      exactly match your theme. Also, you
>      may have to change it every time you
>      change your styles.
> 2. Use client side logic (javascript) to render the dates so that when
>      Google picks the page, it doesn’t
>      quite read whatever (date) is there
>      between the script tags. I prefer this
>      method.

Comment: Do you know if the date value is generated by Google (IE last time it crawled), or does it scrape it from the page?  If it scrapes it from a page, I could hide all date values older than a certain age.

Comment: Check my update that I was typing as you added your comment.